# Is there an easy way to flag posts in the admin area?

Tags: plugins, posts, wp-admin

I'm looking for a plugin, or maybe a bit of code (even another example I can look at that does something similar)...

I'd like to be able to have certain users 'flag' posts, such that when something has been edited once, there could be a checkbox to say 'flag this for subediting', and then that post can be highlighted in the 'posts' section and easily picked out for subbing and then queued for publishing.

Does anyone know of a plugin or something that might accomplish this? I don't really know where to start and my googlings have turned up nothing so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user has a role of contributer/author then cannot publish content. What they do is publish content for review.

Then when an editor/administrator logs in there are numbers shown in the left hand side navigation notifying that there is content waiting to be reviewed.

To me what you are asking for is already part of WordPress. If this isn't functional enough for you can look at [Edit Flow Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/edit-flow/)

Comment: Yeh, that's the thing. I need a double-check on the content ideally, one more over and above wordpress as standard. At first glance this plugin looks like it could well help! I'm going to have a dive in there now, thanks.

Comment: Brilliant. This plugin is exactly what I needed. Custom statuses plus a whole load of other editorial goodness. Thank you very much @Brady!